# Total phase inductance of three phase reactor

Tags: inductor, inductance, reactance, mutual-inductance

Consider a three phase  reactor (inductor) using E-I or E-E laminations with phase winding on each limbs. Now inductance of R phase is given by:

Lr=Lrr+Mry+Mrb

Lrr: Self inductance of R-phase
Mry: Mutual inductance between R and Y phase
Mrb: Mutual inductance between R and B phase.

When such inductance is excited with three phase supply Mry=Mrb=-0.5*Lrr. Hence total inductance will be zero.

This means three phase reactor does not offer any inductance?

Comment: That sounds correct.

Comment: Then how three phase reactors are available commercially specially for passive harmonic filtering?